(solved) rostopic list shows topic but echoing is silent
I am very new to ROS. I have seen the same issue in other questions before, but the difference in my case is that I'm running the ROS master and nodes on one device.
I have a Livox MID-70 LiDAR and need to stream the point cloud to a webserver as an image. To start, I am working in Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL2), have installed ROS Melodic, this Livox ROS Driver and this Livox-SDK as instructed in the LiDAR's user manual. The LiDAR is set up as required via ethernet and Livox Viewer displays the point clouds. I have then followed the steps in the GitHub Repo for the Driver (first link): Edit the launch file to launch the LiDAR based on its serial number which I got from Livox Viewer and ran
roslaunch livox_ros_driver livox_lidar_rviz.launch 

which seemed to run successfully. However, RViz does not display anything. I get the warning "No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [livox_frame] does not exist" and I do not see any messages being received either.
The log does not show any errors, the last entry being "spin".
Running rosnode list shows /livox_lidar_publisher and rostopic list shows /livox/lidar which is also the topic mentioned in the RViz tree. However, when I run rostopic echo /livox/lidar the output is silent.
I get up to the point where I actually can convert my pointcloud to an image and publish that as an image_view without encountering any errors, but I just don't get any output in the end.
The other questions I have encontered seemed to involve several machines where ROS_IP was not set correctly, but it's all running on the same computer in my case and the LiDAR as well as my PC are connected to the same router via LAN cable.
Please let me know if additional information is required, I'm not entirely sure what's relevant information.

Self-answering here:
The issue was actually WSL. After I installed an Ubuntu 18.04 system (dual boot) and re-started the entire process there it worked like a charm.

Please accept your own answer to close the question.
